# Running rails 3 in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment, production

I am having issues running my rails 3 project in production mode.

I am getting tons of routing errors, and they are all in the public folder, images, stylesheets and javascript. No other resources seem to have this problem.

Everything works fine in development and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production.rb file change the following from false to true

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```